# Cannot load assembly problem

Tags: c#, .net

I receive the following error:

Cannot load assembly. Error details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:...' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

This assembly is built with .Net Framework 4.0 and i made sure that all projects in my solution are also built with .Net Framework 4.0.

Any idea why i am getting the error? How can i check which frameworks are loaded with my application?

Comment: check the app.config, do you have some entries like supportedRuntime or requiredRuntime?

Comment: Is this a Windows-Service? If so, have you tried to [install it with the 64bit version of Installutil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229310/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/5229405#5229405)?

Comment: This is my config: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
</configuration>

Comment: This usually happens when there is an x86/x64 issue.

Comment: I checked it - everything build for x86 platform

Answer (score 3):

What is the main executable, i.e. the assembly responsible for deciding which version of the CLR is loaded? Note that it's not just a case of being built *by* .NET 4 - if your executable *targets* .NET 3.5 or lower, it will load in the .NET 2.0 CLR, and your .NET 4 assemblies won't load.

Comment: In the properties of the main executable project, i see that Target Framework is: .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: @Erik: Can you tell us more about the application? What sort of app is it? Do you have anything in the app.config about supportedRuntime?

Comment: I posted the content of the config in the comments of the question. The application is console application. It loads some DLL's from other project (all built with .NET Framework 4.0 - checked)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I Had the same problem until i follow these hints: [BadImageFormatException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) (section "Remarks")

In my case I was trying to load assemblies with call to umnaged code.