# Emgu.CV Not supported Uri format

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I have some program on my 1st pc (everytinh works fine)
but when I copy my full project to another PC and try to run application I get this error :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Formaty identyfikatorów URI nie są obsługiwane.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

and than:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Additional information: Próbowano załadować program w niepoprawnym formacie. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

in this  code:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 pMog11 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(0, 80, false);
```

I have really have no idea what to do with this. What is the problem with Emgu.CV in the 2nd pc?

Comment: Is your deployment target set to x86, 32 bit?

Comment: I dont have any other option to pick, only x86

Comment: Sorry, does that mean yes or no?

Comment: yes is set to x86. Or give me tips where to check it and i will be sure. i think you talking about this option near "run" and "Debug/realise" combobox.

Comment: And if it helps my boths systems are x64 (1st is windows 8, the 2nd where this dont work is windows 7)

Comment: right.  it's a duplicate question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170952/opencv-imgproc-dll-throws-badimageformatexception

Comment: But i dont want to build x64. Why this x84 works finie in my win8 but not in win 7?

Comment: You don't have to use x64. I'm always using OpenCV in x86 on a 64-bits OS and it works fine. You could use Dependency Walker to make sure you are really using the DLLs you think. See my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509582/emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception/13392222#13392222) for a like to Dependency Walker.