# NEventStore Commit Guid, what is it really used for?

Tags: neventstore, commondomain

I understand the `CommitId` is used internally by Jonathan Oliver's event store. 
So far I've always provided a `Guid.NewGuid()` for the `CommitId`.

When would you every want to do anything different?

I don't understand why it is exposed within his common domain Repository.

Can anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: Good question; I can answer it (to allow competing writers who have a shared identifier such as a Command Id) to more cheaply induce fail fast idempotency behavior in the Commit process.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. For those who want to dig into this try here: http://docs.geteventstore.com/dotnet-api/3.6.0/optimistic-concurrency-and-idempotence/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, CommonDomain doesn't try to force a one-size-fits-all opinionated structure.

One way to leverage it is by having writers use their unique incoming Command Id as a CommitId - this means that competing (or retries competing with runs that have yet to time out) will get rejected with a specific exception without needing to enter into/consider/manage Conflict Resolution logic. This is used to fulfil the key tenet of Idempotent Commands.