# vncsharp error on window surface project

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense, vnc

I am new to C# programming with Microsoft Visual C# 2010 and I need help regarding an `XamlParseExcepion` when I attempt to use the `VncSharpWpf.dll` as reference. The following error occurs.

Link of the library and example codes are from : http://d.hatena.ne.jp/horus531/20110515/1305443108

When I tried adding the same codes into the example code provided by the author (i.e importing surface library into the project, the same code works).

I don't know what is causing the library to crash every time on the newly made surface project every time it attempts to load up.

Can someone please guide me on what software/means to use to identify and resolve this types of issue?

The error are:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestVncSharpWpf.SurfaceWindow1' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '5'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=5
  LinePosition=5
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at TestVncSharpWpf.App.Main() in C:\surface\TestVncSharpWpf\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.BadImageFormatException
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'VncSharpWpf, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
       Source=TestVncSharpWpf
       FileName=VncSharpWpf, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = test-PC\test
LOG: DisplayName = VncSharpWpf, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/surface/TestVNCSharpWPF/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : TestVncSharpWpf, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/surface/TestVNCSharpWPF/bin/Debug/VncSharpWpf.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

       StackTrace:
            at TestVncSharpWpf.SurfaceWindow1..ctor()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Did you build the dll yourself, as per the instruction in the link?

Comment: @doctorlove, yes I build the solution from the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the middle of the error messages it says `System.BadImageFormatException` 
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229310/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) suggests the problem may be due to 32bit/64 bit issues. 

Furthermore, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on troubleshooting this say

- If your application uses 32-bit components, make sure that it always runs as a 32-bit application
- Make sure that you are not using a component that was created with a different version of the .NET Framework.
- Make sure that the file image is a valid managed assembly or module.

Comment: I suspected the library was created in another version of visual studio.

I fixed the issue by re-copying the source codes into a new library and compile it with my own VS and it works like a charm :)

Comment: @user1693492 glad you fixed it. :-)