# Could not load file or assembly in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, badimageformatexception

My project uses another lib project as reference.

I get this error when trying to run a project in "Relase" Mode, In "Debug" Mode it works fine.

It says that it cannot load the lib project because :

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'UserManagementProviders,     
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229310/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BadImageFormatException means 32/64 bit mismatch. Check your project configurations. The x86/x64/Any CPU settings must be messed up among Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: you are currect sir, ty

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the difference in `64bit and 32bit` DLL builds and processes.

Try compiling to 32bit by changing `project properties/Build/Platform Target`.