# System.BadImageFormatException in UWP with WPF desktop bridge package

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge, badimageformatexception

I''ve fully and detailed described problem and question in this topic [System.NullReferenceException in AppServiceResponse and System.BadImageFormatException of UWP with WPF desktop bridge package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/), but still have no found answer, what can cause this failure.

Topic link to *Windows Dev Center* above describes assembly, shows all used code with examples, including attempts to fix problem, and other details. So I will put only basic part of task in this stackoverflow topic to avoid text overload in post and focus only on **System.BadImageFormatException**, which provokes **App.Connection** null in **Windows Application Package Project** with connection from **UWP** to **WPF** application, created according to  [UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 3 lesson](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/), (sending of request to desktop extension, read registry key values, and sending of request from desktop extension to UWP, handle requests from desktop code).

I've tried fix it different ways (also described above), but can't find any clue of reason, at least to know where to look for problem, maybe I've missed something, but I can't find related useful answers anywhere in internet

This is the message, but the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` is already in references:

> System.BadImageFormatException   HResult=0x80131058   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime,
> Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or
> one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for
> execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader
> context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)   Source=WpfApp1
> StackTrace:    at
> WpfApp1.MainWindow.d__4.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP\App\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
> 58    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
> stateMachine)    at
> WpfApp1.MainWindow.InitializeAppServiceConnection()    at
> WpfApp1.MainWindow..ctor() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP\App\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
> 37 Inner Exception 1: BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference
> assembly for execution.

Any advice, guide or example would be very helpful

**EDIT 1:** **************************************************************************************************

I've tried all this combinations below two ways **Debug** and **Release**, as well as changed Solution platform "compiler settings", from menu bar of VS target from “Any CPU” to “X86 ” and vice-versa as shown in [System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229310/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly), and from `Solution->Properties->Configuration Properties->Configuration->Project contexts` as well as from `Project->Properties->Build->Platform target`, but functionality and failure equally occurs in all cases:

Current **Configuration Properties**:

```
Console Launcher - AnyCPU
UWP - x86
Package - x86
WPF - AnyCPU
WinForms - AnyCPU
```

Setup all Solution apps to `x86`:

```
Console Launcher - x86
UWP - x86
Package - x86
WPF - x86
WinForms - x86
```

or `x64`:

```
Console Launcher - x64
UWP - x64
Package - x64
WPF - x64
WinForms - x64
```

executes same results by scenario:

[Lessons Part 1 "Run WinForms from UWP"](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) and [Part 2 "Passing parameters"](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/) works successfully, runs application, sends parameters with loading of **WPF** or **WinForms**.

Scenarios from [lesson Part 3](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/) results with same failure, `InitializeAppServiceConnection();` throws  **System.BadImageFormatException**  with direct debug, attempt to run **WPF** or **WinForms** from **UWP**, does nothing with requested application, just shows **Console** Launcher for a second, without any message, and  *Invoke desktop code to read reg key*  throws same **System.NullReferenceException**

Setup all apps to `AnyCPU`, except **UWP**, which bin debug output path, as platform targets drop-down menu from solution or app properties includes only `x64`, `x86`, `ARM`, `ARM64`:

```
Console Launcher - AnyCPU
UWP - x86 
Package - AnyCPU
WPF - AnyCPU
WinForms - AnyCPU
```

throws:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB3270 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture
> of the project being built "x86" and the processor architecture of the
> reference
> "C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP_BD\UWP_BD\Launcher\bin\Debug\Launcher.exe",
> "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
> changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
> the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
> between your project and references, or take a dependency on
> references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
> processor architecture of your project.   Package C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2106

and:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning       The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid
> child element 'WapProjPath' in namespace
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of
> possible elements expected: 'Property, VisualStudioVersion,
> MinimumVisualStudioVersion, AdditionalFileItemNames,
> AllowUnsafeBlocks, AppConfigForCompiler, ApplicationIcon,
> ApplicationRevision, ApplicationVersion, AppDesignerFolder,
> AspNetConfiguration, AspNetCoreHostingModel, AspNetCoreModuleName,
> AssemblyKeyContainerName, AssemblyKeyProviderName, AssemblyName,
> AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile, AssemblyOriginatorKeyFileType,
> AssemblyOriginatorKeyMode, AssemblyType, AutoGenerateBindingRedirects,
> AutorunEnabled, BaseAddress, BootstrapperComponentsLocation,
> BootstrapperComponentsUrl, BootstrapperEnabled, CharacterSet,
> CheckForOverflowUnderflow, CLRSupport, UseDebugLibraries, CodePage,
> Configuration, ConfigurationName, ConfigurationOverrideFile,
> CreateDesktopShortcut, CreateWebPageOnPublish,
> CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents, DebugSecurityZoneURL,
> DebugSymbols, DebugType, DefaultClientScript, DefaultHTMLPageLayout,
> DefaultTargetSchema, DefineConstants, DefineDebug, DefineTrace,
> DelaySign, DisableLangXtns, DisallowUrlActivation,
> CodeAnalysisAd....    Package C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP_BD\UWP_BD\Package\Package.wapproj 49

and `x64`:

```
Console Launcher - AnyCPU
UWP - x64 
Package - AnyCPU
WPF - AnyCPU
WinForms - AnyCPU
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB3270 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture
> of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of
> the reference
> "C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP_BD\UWP_BD\UWP_Control\bin\x64\Debug\UWP_Control.exe",
> "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
> changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
> the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
> between your project and references, or take a dependency on
> references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
> processor architecture of your project.   Package C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2106

I'm not sure, maybe I should change **Minimum Version** to **Anniversary Edition** or to **Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10214)** with creating of **UWP** which default is **Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)**:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** **************************************************************************************************

I'm using `Windows 10 Pro 64-bit OS, x64-basesd processor` with `Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.1.4`, Target Framework: `.NET Framework 4.7.2 Version 4.7.03056`, `Microsoft.NETCore.Universal Windows Platform 6.2.8` Path folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` includes folders: `v7.0A`, `v8.1`, `v8.1A`, `v10.0A`

in `.csproj`:

```
 <TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

I got the same failure **System.BadImageFormatException**, if I change **Minimum Version** to **Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)** same as for **Target Version**, with both previous and new assembly without [Part 1](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) and [Part 2](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/) code.

Also I've followed [Roy Li](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/roy%20%20li/?ws=usercard-mini) suggestion in [System.NullReferenceException in AppServiceResponse and System.BadImageFormatException of UWP with WPF desktop bridge package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/) on *Windows Dev Center*, *"To create a more simple demo to reproduce the problem"*.  So, I've created new package only with **UWP** and **WPF** according only [UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 3](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/) with [UWP_FullTrust_3](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/tree/master/UWP_FullTrust_3).

In previous assembly I have missed [SingleInstance.cs](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/blob/master/UWP_FullTrust_3/FullTrust/SingleInstance.cs) in **WPF** application, but including of this code  into previous or new assembly (without  "Running app" and "passing parameter"), throws error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0017  Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile
> with /main to specify the type that contains the entry
> point.    FullTrust   C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP_BD2\Solution1\FullTrust\SingleInstance.cs 57  Active

on this part of code:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SingleInstanceManager manager = new SingleInstanceManager();
    manager.Run(args);
}
```

**EDIT 3:** **************************************************************************************************

So, for `Windows 10 Pro 64-bit OS, Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.829)` suitable Target version should be `17134`, I'm not sure about Minimum version:

[image]

I've updated `Windows` just few hours ago. Something goes wrong in Targets menu with creating `Windows Application Package Project`, or `UWP,` which does not contains  `17134`, with higher version, I got this message:

[image]

By some reason Target selection menu does not contains `17134` and it is gone for `Windows Application Package Project` too:

[image]

**EDIT 4:** **************************************************************************************************

I've installed SDK version 17134, and selected 17134 for Target Version with  Windows Application Package Project and UWP creation.

I've added code, references, setup, but I got same Error! I'm not sure if I am able to fix it. Maybe complete test project, with actual code will help.

So, here is a full Solution [repository UWP_desktop_bridge](https://github.com/ladooniani/UWP_desktop_bridge).  It is UWP and Console Launcher to WPF, based on [Part 1](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/), [Part 2](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/), [Part 3](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/) of [UWP-FullTrust](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust) lesson by [Stefan Wick MSFT](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/686985/stefan-wick-msft)

Without `InitializeAppServiceConnection();` scenarios from [Part 1](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/), [Part 2](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/) works, but with including `InitializeAppServiceConnection();` to WPF `InitializeComponent();` to get [Part 3](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/) functionality, I got:

> System.BadImageFormatException   HResult=0x80131058   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime,
> Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or
> one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for
> execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader
> context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)   Source=WpfApp1
> StackTrace:    at
> WpfApp1.MainWindow.d__4.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP_desktop-bridge\Solution1\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
> 59    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
> stateMachine)    at
> WpfApp1.MainWindow.InitializeAppServiceConnection()    at
> WpfApp1.MainWindow..ctor() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP_desktop-bridge\Solution1\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
> 38 Inner Exception 1: BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference
> assembly for execution.

and same with `SingleInstance.cs` if using of this part of code:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SingleInstanceManager manager = new SingleInstanceManager();
    manager.Run(args);
}
```

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> CS0017 Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with
> /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

It is similar functionality and failure as in my previous projects.

**EDIT 5**: **************************************************************************************************

At this time, I've carefully created copy-paste  build, based on [ZhuMingHao/AppSerViceTest demo](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/AppSerViceTest) given in answer by [Nico Zhu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254781/nico-zhu-msft) on related question [Send speech recognition args.Result as parameter in UWP desktop-bridge package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961757/send-speech-recognition-args-result-as-parameter-in-uwp-desktop-bridge-package):

Debug loads `UWP` and `WPF` successfully. With click on the `Click` button with in `UWP` [AppSerViceTest/AppServiceTest/MainPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/AppSerViceTest/blob/master/AppServiceTest/MainPage.xaml.cs):

I got same exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.

With click on `WPF` `Send Message` button, it is just closes `WPF` app, `UWP` `StatusBlock` and `InfoBlock` shows nothing.

Direct debug of `WPF` and click `Send message` button, throws a different content of the same **System.BadImageFormatException**:

> System.BadImageFormatException   HResult=0x80131058   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime,
> Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or one of its
> dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.
> They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)   Source=WpfApp1   StackTrace:
> at WpfApp1.MainWindow.<Button_Click_1>d__5.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\UWP\UWP_DB_SR\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
> 91    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
> stateMachine)    at WpfApp1.MainWindow.Button_Click_1(Object sender,
> RoutedEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
> RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()    at
> System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
> e)    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object
> sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> target)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
> RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender,
> MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> target)    at
> System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
> RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
> trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
> input)    at
> System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
> inputReport)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
> InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
> Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
> hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
> handled)    at
> System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
> Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
> priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
> numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
> Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
> frame)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
> at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
> System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
> System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
> System.Windows.Application.Run()    at WpfApp1.App.Main() Inner
> Exception 1: BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly
> for execution.

**SOLUTION**: **************************************************************************************************

Solution answer given by  [Stefan Wick MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686985/stefan-wick-msft) to question described also on WDC topic [System.NullReferenceException in AppServiceResponse and System.BadImageFormatException of UWP with WPF desktop bridge package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/) on **System.BadImageFormatException** with [particular UWP desktop-bridge app communication project](https://github.com/ladooniani/UWP_desktop_bridge), based on [UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 3](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/) example [UWP-FullTrust/UWP_FullTrust_3/](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/tree/master/UWP_FullTrust_3) as well as solver my copy of [Nico Zhu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254781/nico-zhu-msft) solution [ZhuMingHao/AppSerViceTest](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/AppSerViceTest):

My incorrect:

- Program Files (x86)\Reference
  Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
- Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd

Must be correct references setup:

- ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference
  Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
- ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows
  Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Windows.winmd

Comment: Have you tried setting all projects in your solution consistently to the same architecture (x86 or x64)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229310/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly)

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT Hello, first of all, thank you for your feedback, guide and examples!
Please, check my results in added "EDIT" section above.

Comment: @Rekshino Hello, I've tried change solution platform from menu bar of VS  target from  “Any CPU” to “X86 ” and vice-versa, but result is same.

Comment: Try to change it directly by project->properties->build->target platform.

Comment: @Rekshino Result in EDIT section checked with changing two ways from `Solution->Properties->Configuration Properties->Configuration->Project contexts`, as well as from `Project->Properties->Build->Platform target`. Should I change **Minimum Version** to **Anniversary Edition** or to **Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10214)** with creating of **UWP**, which default is **Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)**?

Comment: I don't know. Try it..

Comment: Minimum version needs to be at least 14393 (aka Windows 10 Anniversary Update 1607), because that's when we introduced the Desktop Bridge feature. What version of Windows 10 are you running on? What version of the Windows 10 SDK are you using? Your Target version should match that.

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT Sorry for late reply. I've added new EDIT 2 to question. Please check my results, I still can't figure out with problem

Comment: Can you share your complete test project? Without seeing your actual code we can only speculate. Btw, I am curious why you are setting Target version to 14393? The target version meaning is highest version of Windows you have tested with (that's different from minimum version, which is the minimum the app can run on). Are you really running on that version of OS and SDK? It's a couple of years old by now. Can you try on current version of OS and SDK?

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT Hi, please check my EDIT 3. So on `OS Build 17134.829` suitable Target version should be `17134`, not sure about Minimum version, but Targets menu with creating `UWP` and after update also with `Windows Application Package Project`, does not contains `17134`, but only higher version

Comment: Please install Windows SDK version 17134 from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: I debugged the project from your repo. The references in the WPF project were not set up correctly. I added a new project WpfApp2 to the solution with your exact same code and added the below references and it works fine now: 1) "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll"   2) "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Windows.winmd"

Comment: Glad you got it working. I posted this as answer now. Please mark as answered to close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs when referencing the Windows Runtime libraries incorrectly from the non-UWP project (WPF, Winforms, Console, etc.). Be sure to reference them as follows

1. In the "Add Reference …" dialog click "Browse …" and set the filter to "All Files (*.*)"
2. Navigate to "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll"
3. Navigate to  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\{*TargetVersion*}\Windows.winmd"