# WPF Project .NET Core show window from WPF project .NET framework

Tags: wpf, .net-core, crystal-reports

I have a project on WPF .NET Core. I added another project for Crystal Reports and I am trying to invoke the report window from inside main project.

Not implemented, this message appears:

> `System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly' CrystalReportWpfApplication1, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null '. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

The calling code is:

```
new CrystalReportWpfApplication1.Window1().Show();
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some more details about the two projects and how they should work together

Comment: it would appear that the assemblies may be of differing architectures as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229310/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly

Comment: The error message has changed
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'