# System.BadImageFormatException What does that mean?

Tags: c#, exception, badimageformatexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.BadImageFormatException “invalid format” when trying to install service with installutil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323140/system-badimageformatexception-invalid-format-when-trying-to-install-service-w)

When I install my Windows Service App, I get the following exception:

> Error 1001. exception occurred while initializing the installation :
>   System.BadImageFormatException: could not load file or assembly
>   .....file.exe or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load
>   a program with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that one of your assemblies is compiled for 64-bit mode and tries to load a 32-bit one, or vise versa.