# Getting Exception when running nunit tests from command line

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm a newbie to C# (.Net ) world, I've created a hello world test in Nunit and trying to run it form command line but getting following error.

Can someone please help to understand what I'm missing ?

The Nunit version I'm using is 2.6.3

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin> .\nunit-console.exe /xml:testout.xml "C:\My_Data\Liquid\API _Automation\abc_Test_proj\abc_Test_Proj\S
umesh_Test_Proj\bin\Debug\abc_Test_Proj.dll"
NUnit-Console version 2.6.3.13283
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5485 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
Unhandled Exception:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'abc_Test_Proj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of it
s dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'abc_Test_Proj, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Server stack trace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackC
rawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, Sta
ckCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.RemoteTestAgent.AgentRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin>
```

Comment: I would guess your programm is compiled in 64bit and you tried to test it in 32bit.

Comment: Does it help to switch the start location so you are located in your project folder instead of the nunit folder.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe" /xml:testout.xml abc_Test_Proj.dll

Comment: Maybe this it helping?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658976/system-badimageformatexceptioncould-not-load-file-or-assembly-incorrect-forma

Comment: Thanks, the solution mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875108/system-badimageformatexception-caused-by-nunit-project helped me to overcome this.