# Windows Service cannot install on other platforms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, platform

I created a simple windows service,the platform of the project is **Any CPU** and i installed my service using **installutil.exe** command. Then I uninstalled the service and set the platform to **X64**. But after this, i cannot install the service. I got the following error

> *Exception occured while initializing the installation: System.BadImageFormatException:Could not load file or assembly -- or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.*

I want to change the platform to **X64** for using some dlls. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using `installutil` from `%windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vX.x.xxx` or from `%windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\vX.x.xxx`?

Comment: i have both %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vX.x.xxx and %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\vX.x.xxx. How can i use the Framework64 version

Comment: By specifying the full path to the one you want to use? (Which is pretty well the standard answer to any question about how to select which version of a command line tool will be used)

Comment: it works successfully. I installed using the Framework64 path. But the uninstall fails.

Comment: How to uninstall the service using %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\vX.x.xxx.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the x86 platform, the dll run in mixed mode and will work with your service

Answer (score 0):

The InstallUtill.exe is platform-speciffic

check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2160932/891715

also, this will get you the correct path to the correct version:

```
 string InstallUtilPath = Path.Combine(
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(),
     "installutil.exe");
```

Also a little warning: be especially carefull if you're using the setup project to install your serveces. It embedes installutil into itself (and usually it isn't the correct version...).

Comment: SetupProject is crap - which is why it was retired. WIX to go. SetupProject is not even able to make a standard compliant installer when you just add a text file, pretty much.

Comment: @TomTom - regrettably, some people pushed for it, and it's [coming back](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)

Comment: F***, I hoped that one dies for good. WIX is all you really need.